# Do I need to change my UK visa from Visitor to Business?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, change-purpose-of-travel

I have a UK visitor visa of 5 years valid till March 2018. I am visiting UK every year for 20-25 days.

Now, I am planning to invest in a business of my friend in the UK. For the same I plan to apply for a entrepreneur visa. But before that I need to make some visits to decide for the same before I apply and invest. For this do I need to change my Tourist Visa to Business visa? Please note that the tourist visa is still valid upto Mar2018.

I fear if I make frequent visits, I may be stopped/refused at the airport. Last year, I was advised by the immigration officer at the airport to change my visa to business when I made two consecutive visits in a month.

Comment: Sounds like your conversation with the IO was garbled and you misinterpreted or misheard. The rules changed in 2015 such that there is no 'business visa'; there's only a Standard Visitor Visa.

Comment: Is there any restriction of frequency in visits to the UK on a general Visit Visa ?

Answer (score 5):

Scares me how an IO fails to keep himself up-to-date with such Major changes.

As Gayot Fow wrote in a comment, there is **no such thing** as a UK business visa; rather, the Standard Visitor visa covers the most common types of visits (such as tourism, busisness and private visits)

So no, you are **not** supposed to get another type of visa

Comment: Thank you Gayot Fow and Thank you Crazydre for answering. Really appreciated your help.

Comment: Is there any restriction of frequency in visits to the UK on a general Visit Visa ?

Comment: @user60110 No formal restriction, no, but if they Think you're trying to live in the Uk through frequent visits, you'll be sent back and likely banned from re-entry for a couple of years to come